# Getting an html element to cover a specific part of the background image at all times

Tags: css, image, background

I have this Background img that I would like to put a contact form inside the computer screen as in the image bellow,

Is there a way to get the form to always stick at this position no matter what screen size (and without adding numerous @media queries..)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the % unit in the css, so it will always going to be proportionally to the screen.

Ex:

```css
form {
  width: 100%;
}


.form_input-short {
  width: 80%;
}

.form_input-big {
  width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tried that already, for some reason it will go off at some point.. and also what works in Opra will not work in Firefox ect..

Comment: Maybe the form wrapper is not defined as 100% too. Start painting the background of the elements to see who is disturbing the behavior you want. =D